# Integrating Flask and ReactJS with the use of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, flask

**TL;DR:** How am I able to integrate/implement a jQuery code(please see below) into ReactJS?

Greetings everyone. Amateur user of ReactJS and Flask here.
I'm just looking for a solution on how to integrate a jQuery code into ReactJS  or even other alternatives considering the implementation in the lifecycle becomes different into ReactJS.

Currently, this snippet (kindly see the boilerplate jQuery code below) communicates with Flask's CRUD operations very well which sends the chosen image from `FileReader()` in base64 form and responds with the corresponding prediction (by an ML model) when the `#predict-button` is pressed.

```
<body>
    <input id="image-selector" type="file">
    <button id="predict-button">Predict</button>
    <p style="font-weight:bold">Predictions</p>
    <p>foo1: <span id="foo1"></span></p>
    <p>foo2:   <span id="foo2"></span></p>
    <p>foo3:   <span id="foo3"></span></p>
    <img id="selected-image" src=""/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
let base64Image;
    $("#image-selector").change(function() {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            let dataURL = reader.result;
            $('#selected-image').attr("src",dataURL);
            base64Image = dataURL.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","");
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL($("#image-selector")[0].files[0]);
        $("#foo1").text("");
        $("#foo2").text("");
        $("#foo3").text("");
    });

    $("#predict-button").click(function(event){
        let message = {
            image: base64Image
        }
        console.log(message);
        $.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict",JSON.stringify(message),function(response){
            $("#foo1").text(response.prediction.foo1.toFixed(6));
            $("#foo2").text(response.prediction.foo2.toFixed(6));
            $("#foo3").text(response.prediction.foo3.toFixed(6));
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Not to mention, I don't need the `FileReader()` anymore as I have this function `captureShot()` from 'react-webcam' in ReactJS which returns a base64 encoded string of the current webcam image.

```
  captureShot = () => {
    const screenshot = this.webcam.getScreenshot();
    this.setState({ imageData: screenshot });

  }
```

These kind of questions arise:

1. Can this be implemented in ReactJS?
2. If so, how? Will it be through `ComponentDidMount()` or inside the `render()`?
3. If not, is using Express the way to do the CRUD operations in ReactJS en route to Flask?

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thank you very much for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sheer excitement of asking this odd question surely have baffled three downvoters ha. Thank you for the kind advice @jmargolisvt, I've managed to do it and my Flask server can now finally communicate well with my ReactJS - project is donezo!

Here's the solution just in-case anyone's interested.

```
export default class App extends Component { 
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bar: { foo1: null, foo2: null, foo3: null },
    }
  }

captureShot = () => {
    const screenshot = this.webcam.getScreenshot();
    let base64Image = screenshot.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","");
    this.setState({ 
      imageData: screenshot,
     });

    let message = {
      image: base64Image
    }

   fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(message)
    })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();  
  })
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState( {
      bar: {
        foo1: (data.prediction.foo1.toFixed(3)),
        foo2: (data.prediction.foo2.toFixed(3)),
        foo3: (data.prediction.foo3.toFixed(3)),
      }
    })   
  })
   .catch(error => this.setState({ error,  bar: { foo1: null, foo2: null, foo3: null }, }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably too broad for SO, but the short answer is "yes" you can do this. To get you thinking in the React way is probably the best I can offer for an answer without building it for you.

Your `image-selector` div will become a React component.  It will have an `onChange` prop that will point to a custom class method where you can do the rest of your business logic.  Your `predict-button` will similarly become a component, this time with `onClick` as your prop.  Since you are running all your functions as a response to an action, you don't need any bootstrapped data in `constructor` or `componentDidMount`.

You can use native `fetch` or similar libraries to replace your `$.post` call too.  In the end you won't need any of your jQuery code, but if you convert your code piece-by-piece, you will get there and learn a lot along the way.  I suggest using Create React App for an easy way into the architecture.

Comment: Thank you for replying! That defo gave me a better insight on where to start. I think it's ideal to start with the function `captureShot()` considering `const screenshot = this.webcam.getScreenshot();` gives a base64 format and it's just what I need for now. Any tips on getting rid of the `FileReader()` and replacing it with an already-captured, encoded image instead?